# FacebookPermissionException error whilst trying to use php to post to facebook "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I am receiving an error while trying to post to a facebook wall using php.
The error is as follows ~ PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookPermissionException' with message '(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action' in /facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php:128

The code I am using is

```
// include required files form Facebook SDK
$dir = 'facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/';

require_once( $dir.'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( $dir.'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( $dir.'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );

require_once( $dir.'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( $dir.'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );

require_once( $dir.'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( $dir.'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( $dir.'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( $dir.'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( $dir.'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( $dir.'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( $dir.'Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( $dir.'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( $dir.'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( $dir.'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

require_once( $dir.'Facebook/FacebookClientException.php' );
require_once( $dir.'Facebook/FacebookPermissionException.php' );
require_once( $dir.'Facebook/FacebookServerException.php' );
require_once( $dir.'Facebook/FacebookThrottleException.php' );

use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;

use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

use Facebook\FacebookClientException;
use Facebook\FacebookPermissionException;
use Facebook\FacebookServerException;
use Facebook\FacebookThrottleException;

// start session
session_start();

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'app-id' , 'secret' );

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://f13.tv/share/test01.php' );



// see if a existing session exists
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {

    // create new session from saved access_token
    $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

    $page_id = '187295794639218';

    // get page access token
    $access_token = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/' . $page_id,  array( 'fields' => 'access_token' ) ))
    ->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();

    // save access token in variable for later use  
    $access_token = $access_token['access_token'];

    // post to page
    $page_post = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/'. $page_id.'/feed', array(
        'access_token' => $access_token,
        'name' => 'Facebook API: Posting As A Page using Graph API v2.x and PHP SDK 4.0.x',
        'link' => 'https://www.webniraj.com/2014/08/23/facebook-api-posting-as-a-page-using-graph-api-v2-x-and-php-sdk-4-0-x/',
        'caption' => 'The Facebook API lets you post to Pages you administrate via the API. This tutorial shows you how to achieve this using the Facebook PHP SDK v4.0.x and Graph API 2.x.',
        'message' => 'Check out my new blog post!',   ) ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();

    // return post_id
    print_r( $page_post );

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This error occurring because **you do not have permission to post on pages.**
Permission ***publish_actions*** is required to post on pages.
Your Login URL would look like this:
`$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('publish_actions'));` /* login url with permission */ 
In order to check **Permissions Granted** by user do something like this:
`$user_permissions = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/permissions'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className())->asArray();`
`var_dump($user_permissions);`

Comment: Thanks for your help - the dump of the user permissions dumps, but I still can't seem to get the bit of code to work which would add a post to the page wall. @rakesh

Comment: What _user permissions_ dumps?@martyish

Comment: var_dump($user_permissions);  @rakesh

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug affecting thousands of developers since last week, follow this bug report and post there to speed up Facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1655744048061679/